# Composer/Laravel: Not update specific folder inside vendor

Tags: laravel, pdf, composer-php, updates, dompdf

I have installed laravel latest version ..In my application i have used barryvdh/laravel-dompdf package. And i made some font changes in the pdf packages..

Now my problem is while giving composer update this "***barryvdh/laravel-dompdf***" do not get update ..It should be ignore then only my changes are not affected..

```
composer update
```

And here is the package I tried to add to my project: https://github.com/barryvdh/laravel-dompdf

Any suggestions ?

Comment: What kind of changes did you make? In [comments](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40355301/composer-laravel-not-update-specific-folder-inside-vendor#comment67967133_40355572) you mention adding a font, is that the extent of your change?

Answer (score 0):

You should never make any changes in classes inside `vendor`. You should [extend those classes](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.inheritance.php) instead to change standard functionality.

Comment: @Trent, it's impossible to teach you how to do it with one answer. I'd recommend you to read some good OOP book and some tutorials to understand how does it work.

Answer (score 0):

@Trent is not so difficult to explain.

if you read about OOP, you will get the idea about hierarchy, which means that a class can have a "father" which it extends.

So in this case the vendors in Laravel are loaded by default. So lets say you have a vendor class called "FatherClass", if you want to extend the functionality of it you can create a "ChildClass" extending of it. This is a simple example:

```
  <?php 

  Class FatherClass{
     public function method_one(){

       return "Hi, This is method 1";
     }
  }

  Class ChildClass extends FatherClass{

     public function method_two(){
       return "Hi, This is method 2";
     }
  }
  //So now you can create a child object and will have the father and its own methods.
  $childObject = new ChildClass();
  $childObject->method_one(); // Hi, This is method 1
  $childObject->method_two(); // Hi, This is method 2
  ?>
```

So how is this good to understand it for vendors?

Well in your case this is the class that you should extend PDF (https://github.com/barryvdh/laravel-dompdf/blob/master/src/PDF.php).

So it should be something like :

```
<?php
   class NewPdfClass extends PDF{

   }
```

You should be able now to override the methods or create new ones for your purposes.

Let me know if this helps.

Comment: I have added some fonts inside the dompdf package inside vendor folder... If i give composer update ..is the package get updated ??? I can't import the fonts from other side to change the pdf font ....